# getFloatArray is not receiving array

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent, bundle

I'm working with a list:

```
  List<Float> subjects = Arrays.asList(0f,0f,0f,0f,0f,0f);
  List<Float> question9 = Arrays.asList(0f,0f);
```

And I want to put send it to  another activity using Intent like this:

```
Intent iQuizz= new Intent(BachelorsResults.this, Results.class);
iQuizz.putExtra(BACHELOR, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
iQuizz.putExtra(QUESTION_9, question9.toArray());
iQuizz.putExtra(FAILED_SUBJECTS, subjects.toArray());

BachelorsResults.this.startActivity(iQuizz);
```

In the another activity I'm trying to receive float values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
float[] q9= extras.getFloatArray(QUESTION_9);
float[] fSubjects= extras.getFloatArray(FAILED_SUBJECTS);
```

But once I start this second activiy it launchs this Exception:

```
3-05 15:30:28.221 24640-24640/citrapp.exatec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: citrapp.exatec, PID: 24640
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{citrapp.exatec/citrapp.exatec.Resultados}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                at citrapp.exatec.Resultados.onCreate(Resultados.java:85)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Somehow when I pass them to the another activity, float arrays become nulls, because I test extras.getFloatArray inside the first activity and it shows the content, but in the second activity it doesn't. If somebody could help me would be awesome..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `getIntent().getExtras()` with `getIntent().getFloatArrayExtra()`.

Comment: Didn't work.. 

float[] q9 = getIntent().getFloatArrayExtra(QUESTION_9);

float[] fSubjects= getIntent().getFloatArrayExtra(FAILED_SUBJECTS);

it's still reporting a NullPointerException

Comment: Can you let me know what is in `Resultados.java:85` ? Is it crashing because you are calling `toString()` on the float arrays?